# Twitter OAuth with Android, from REST 1.0 without Login to REST 1.1 with Login

Tags: android, json, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have an app, that uses the public part of the Twitter API, the one which does not require a login, but with the update, the login is required, so I need to implement OAuth. I've seen there are libraries like Twitter4j who makes this easier, but my app has a lot of code, and I don't want to rewrite it, not now, so I've think to use **SCRIBE** or **oauth-signpost**, but I don't really know how to.

I've read a lot of webs tutorials, and github projects but they don't work for me (maybe I'm stupid).

I've being thinking in the next things, correct me if I'm wrong.

1. **An initial activity with the login button, only a button, who shows
   a web view with twitter.**
2. **Shared preferences of the Token y Token Secret.**
3. **A Little change on my get json function, in the HTTPclient, if I'm not wrong which passes a header with the token, token secret, app key and app key secret.**

After a week of reading, I think that I understand how it works, but I can't do even a simple new project make a connection.

I know that I should made 3 petitions if I'm not wrong, and after the second, open a webview with a link that is in the second request, an is there where the user logs in.

With the different alternatives, I think that the best option for what I want to do, is **oauth-signpost**, but I can't find examples, I found a few, but they crashed...

If anyone could help me with this, a little explanation, or an example, but a simple thing, because I'm losing my mind, and I can't continue because the API 1.0 is going to be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Temboo. It simplifies the OAuth process for a number of APIs, including Twitter. It works like this:

1. Run the `InitializeOAuth` step. This returns an authorization URL that you can show to your users. They need to follow the instructions on this page to authenticate with your app.
2. Run the `FinalizeOAuth` step. This takes as input the callback ID that your user generated when they authenticated via the URL you showed them in the previous step. The result of this step is the access token you need.

Full details here: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Twitter/OAuth/

Also, you can play with, and see source code for, how Temboo simplifies OAuth for Facebook [here](https://www.temboo.com/examples). The twitter support works the same way.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)